# Help showing associativity when multiplying group element by vector.

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces, modules, representation-theory

Consider a representation $\rho=(\rho_{ij})$ of a group $G$ of degree $d$ and a $d$-dimensional vector space. I want to turn $V$ into a $G$-module by defining the action of $x\in G$ on each of the vectors of a basis of $V$ by
$$
x \boldsymbol{v}_i=\sum_j \rho_{i j}(x) \boldsymbol{v}_j
$$
and for a general $\boldsymbol{v}=\sum \alpha_i \boldsymbol{v}_i$ in $V$:
$$
x\left(\sum \alpha_i \boldsymbol{v}_i\right)=\sum \alpha_i \rho_{i j}(x) \boldsymbol{v}_j
$$
For $V$ to be a $G$-module I need the multiplication so defined to be associative, $(xy)\boldsymbol{v}=x(y\boldsymbol{v})$, however, I have a hard time showing. Consider
$$
\begin{aligned}
& (x y)\left(\sum_i \alpha_i \boldsymbol{v}_i\right)=\sum_{i, j} \alpha_i \rho_{i j}(x y) \boldsymbol{v}_j=\sum_{i, j, k} \alpha_i \rho_{i k}(x) \rho_{k j}(y) \boldsymbol{v}_j \\
& x\left(y \sum_i \alpha_i \boldsymbol{v}_i\right)=x \sum_{i, k} \alpha_i \rho_{i k}(y) \boldsymbol{v}_k=\sum_{i, k} \alpha_i \rho_{i k}(y) x \boldsymbol{v}_k=\sum_{i, j, k} \alpha_i \rho_{i k}(y) \rho_{k j}(x) \boldsymbol{v}_j
\end{aligned}
$$
These expressions don't seem to be identical, so what is wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Replace
$$x \boldsymbol{v}_i=\sum_j \rho_{i j}(x) \boldsymbol{v}_j$$
by
$$x \boldsymbol{v}_j=\sum_i\rho_{i j}(x) \boldsymbol{v}_i.$$